# How to reload userform when button is clicked?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have 2 userforms that are working as expected apart from the fact that when I close form2 and refill form1 and press "add" it does not take me back to the start of form2. It shows the last part that I was at previously.

When I press the close button on form2 I want it to reload the next time Add on form1 is clicked.

```vb
'Public because we want it to be active for all macros.
'Aim to stopped a loop when user click on a button
Public stopped, Non As Boolean 

Public Sub closebut_Click()
Load Addform
Addform.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub savebut_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim newrow As ListRow

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("New Product")

Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("NewMat")

erow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

ws.Cells(erow, 1).Value = Me.EAN.Value
ws.Cells(erow, 2).Value = Me.MatCode.Value
ws.Cells(erow, 3).Value = Me.Des.Value

Do While stopped = True

Loop
Me.Label1.Visible = False
Me.Label2.Visible = False
Me.Label3.Visible = False
Me.Label4.Visible = True
Me.EAN.Visible = False
Me.MatCode.Visible = False
Me.Des.Visible = False
Me.closebut.Visible = True
Me.savebut.Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_initialize()

Do While stopped = True

Loop
Me.Label1.Visible = True
Me.Label2.Visible = True
Me.Label3.Visible = True
Me.Label4.Visible = False
Me.EAN.Visible = True
Me.MatCode.Visible = True
Me.Des.Visible = True
Me.closebut.Visible = False
Me.savebut.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Your question is not so clear, in terms of used forms identification. Which of the two mentioned forms is `Addform`? Form 2? Then, on which form does `savebut_Click()` code exist? Is it the mentioned "Add " one? If not, since you told us "I want it to reload the next time Add on form1 is clicked", you should show which part of this code you think should "show" the desired form...

Comment: Hi sorry,

Addform is form2

A code is put into "Scan" which is form1 and if it is not recognized then user will press a button to add the code which opens "Addform", the code copies into here and a couple more details are entered. User then presses "Savebut" and only "label4" and "closebut" are shown. When close is clicked "addform" is then hidden and "scan" form is shown.

The next time that the "add" button is pressed after the first cycle instead of the "addform" loading at start for the extra details it is loading at the end and only showing "label4" and "closebut".

Comment: I need

'''Public Sub closebut_Click()
Load Addform
Addform.Hide
End Sub'''

to basically say refresh "addform" to the beginning and hide so that the next time it is loaded the "addform" is at the start

Comment: I cannot get you, sorry... A lot of words not related to my clarification questions. What does **if it is not recognized then user will press a button to add the code which opens "Addform"** mean? What is to be "recognized"? How to "add the code"? Does your application write code? Is it a secret code, since you do not show it to us? Or is it somewhere in the question and I am missing it? If so, please point me in the right direction.

Comment: Still kind of confused but in the `Add` button of form1, try `Unload AddForm: AddForm.Show`, it should reinitialise a new instance of `AddForm`. Don't attempt to *refresh* `AddForm` in the close button, just hide it.

Comment: Hi, sorry that I caused confusion with my explanations. Using unload instead of .hide has worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use use vbModeless in your userform show event.

Something like this:

```
Userform1.Show (vbModeless)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Userform2 evets select **UserForm_Deactivate** and write **Unload Me** it will be closed **Userform2** , when you open *Userform2* it will reload. may it help you

```
Private Sub UserForm_Deactivate()
Unload Me
End Sub
```